# How to avoid receiving packet when receiver is not ready in UDP?

Tags: udp

I know in default the sent data is stored in buffer of receiver waiting to be received. But I hope the recevier doesn't receive packet before it use recvfrom(). Is it possible?

Comment: Huh? The application can't receive the datagram until it asks the network stack for it.

Comment: Really? So you mean all sent in packets are lost before I use recvfrom()?

Comment: No, they're queued because the application can't receive them yet. The application cannot receive a packet until it uses `recvfrom`. So what is the issue?

Comment: I want the packets sent to the receiver get dumped before it is ready(use recvfrom) to make sure they wouldn't be received.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If the datagram is buffered, it is in the socket receive buffer before the receiver calls `recvfrom()`. That is the meaning of buffering.

Answer (score -1):

Set the socket non-blocking. Call `recvfrom` in a loop until you get an `EWOULDBLOCK` error.

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanation from the downvoter. This is the correct solution.